# fetch sql query to become a variable

Tags: java, mysql, variables

I'm looking all over the net for this problem, I don't know maybe I just cant explain what I'm trying to do.

```
Statement stmtttt = con.createStatement();
 ResultSet resultttt = stmtttt.executeQuery("select * from logs_pms_t_project where p_id="+p_id+" ");
                    while(resultttt.next())
                                      {
 out.println(" <span class>" + resultttt.getString("phase_id")+ "</span>" );
                                      }
```

In that code, I'm trying to display a certain column from the database -- the `phase_id`. So that I can store it as variable to a `String`.

```
String phase_id=???;
```

How can I do that?

Comment: `String phaseId = resultttt.getString("phase_id")`  -- Is that not working?

Comment: No sir, it is not working. I already tried that.

Comment: Have you verified that the query actually runs successfully?  Try your query outside of your program (like in the mysql client) and make sure that you should really be getting something back.

Comment: I think the `while` loop is the problem of mine a while ago. Because when I follow the advice of @radoh. It works, following what he said that the last query will be read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to accomplish, but looking at the SQL, I think you're expecting just 1 row returned, therefore an `if` will do, no need for a `while`. So then you can assign the `phase_id` var like this

```
ResultSet resultttt = stmtttt.executeQuery("select * from logs_pms_t_project where p_id="+p_id+" ");
String phase_id = null;
if (resultttt.next()) {
    phase_id = resultttt.getString("phase_id");
    // out.println ... ?
}
```

You could do the same with the `while` loop of course, but if the query returned more than 1 row, it `phase_id` would contain the id from the last row.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the cause of your problems is that you are not enclosing `p_id` in quotes. In general, passing parameters to queries like this is a bad practice. Suggest you read up on `java.sql.PreparedStatement` - it has a `setString()` method for setting query parameters.

This is called 'SQL injection vulnerability': if you are reading `p_id` from an input, the user could have entered something like `foo"; drop table logs_pms_t_project;`, and erase all your data.